# Does Visual Studio for Mac support ASP MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio

I've tested creating ASP MVC 5 projects with the latest Visual Studio for Mac. So far some things don't seem to work 100%, like Razor Intellisense (I can live with that) and custom route settings.

I know that it isn't officially supported, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't work, otherwise the project template type wouldn't be there.

My question is:

Can I develop ASP MVC 5 web applications with Visual Studio Mac? Are there problems I will encounter, and if so, can I work around those? How do I deploy it?

I can't use ASP Core (yet) as I have the hosting I must use doesn't support it; only ASP.NET 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020 this is possible to create MVC projects in VisualStudio for Mac.

[image: Working Mac MVC image]

Answer (score 0):

No. Applications written targeting the .NET Framework, which the non-.NET Core MVC is based, are not supported. The .NET Framework was built for Windows only. It does not run natively on a Mac.

Comment: I know it isn't officially supported. I updated my question.

Comment: @JohanV it’s impossible. The Framework was built for Windows, not Mac